# Reading the huge image data for training classifiers

Tags: python, machine-learning, label, training-data

I am new to python and Machine Learning. I have a huge image dataset of cars having more than 27000 images and labels. I am trying to create a dataset so I can use it in my training classifier, but ofcourse handling this amount of data will be a real pain for the Memory, and that's where I am stuck. At first I was trying to do something like this.

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpg
import cv2
import gc
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
import gc
import resource
import h5py

bbox = "/run/media/fdai5182/LAMAMADAN/Morethan4000samples/data/labels"
imagepath = "/run/media/fdai5182/LAMAMADAN/Morethan4000samples/data/image"



training_data = []
training_labels = []
count = 0


for root, _, files in os.walk(bbox):
    cdp = os.path.abspath(root)
    for rootImage , _ , fileImage in os.walk(imagepath):
        cdpimg = os.path.abspath(r) 
        for f in files:
            ct = 0
            name,ext = os.path.splitext(f)
            for fI in fileImage:
                n , e = os.path.splitext(fI)
                if name == n and ext == ".txt" and e == ".jpg":
                    cip = os.path.join(cdp,f)
                    cipimg = os.path.join(cdpimg,fI)
                    txt = open(cip,"r")
                    for q in txt:
                        ct = ct + 1
                        if ct == 3:
                            x1 = int(q.rsplit(' ')[0])
                            y1 = int(q.rsplit(' ')[1])
                            x2 = int(q.rsplit(' ')[2])
                            y2 = int(q.rsplit(' ')[3])  
                            try:
                                read_img = mpg.imread(cipimg)
                                read_img = read_img.astype('float32')
                                read_img_bbox = read_img[y1:y2, x1:x2,:]
                                resize_img = cv2.cv2.resize(read_img_bbox,(300,300))
                                resize_img /= 255.0 
                                training_labels.append(int(cipimg.split('\\')[4]))                                 


                                training_data.append(resize_img)
                                print("len Of Training_data",len(training_data))
                                training_labels.append(int(cipimg.split('/')[8]))
                                del resize_img
                                print("len Of Training Labels", len(training_labels))
                                gc.collect()                                    
                            except Exception as e:
                                print("Error",str(e), cip)
                            count = count + 1
                            print(count)    
                    txt.flush()
                    txt.close() 




np.save('/run/media/fdai5182/LAMA MADAN/Training_Data_4000Samples',training_data)
np.save('/run/media/fdai5182/LAMA MADAN/Training_Labels_4000Samples',training_labels)




print("DONE")
```

But it always gives me a huge Memory error after reading images even on 32gb RAM.

So, for that I want to do some other steps which may be useful taking less memory and get this working. 
The Steps I want to do are as follows.

1. allocate np array X  of shape  N,150,150,3/300,300,3 of type
   float32 (not astype)
2. iterate through images and fill each row of array X with 150,150,3 image pixels
3. normalize in-place: X /= 255
4. Write in file (.npy format)

What I did till now is

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.iamge as mpg
import numpy as np

bbox = "/run/media/fdai5182/LAMAMADAN/Morethan4000samples/data/labels"
imagepath = "/run/media/fdai5182/LAMAMADAN/Morethan4000samples/data/image"

for root, _, files in os.walk(bbox):
    cdp = os.path.abspath(root)
    for rootImage, _, fileImage in os.walk(imagepath):
        cdpimg = os.path.abspath(rootImage)
        for f in files:
            ct = 0
            name,ext = os.path.splitext(f)
            for fI in fileImage:
                n , e = os.path.splitext(fI)
                if name == n and ext == ".txt" and e == ".jpg":
                   nparrayX = np.zeros((150,150,3)).view('float32')
                   cip = os.path.join(cdp,f)
                   cipImg = os.path.join(cdpimg,fI)
                   read_image = mpg.imread(cip)
                   resize_image = cv2.cv2.resize(read_image,(150,150))
```

Am I on the right path? 
Also, How can I fill each row of imageformat with 150,150,3 image pixels. I don't want to use list anymore as they take more Memory and time consuming. 
Please help me through this.

Also, as a new member if the question is not obeying the rules and regulations of StackOverflow please tell me and I will edit it more.

Thank you,

Comment: Usually when dealing with image data, models are trained in batches, not all at once.

Comment: What library are you using to define your model?

Answer (score 0):

Both tensorflow/keras and pytorch provide data set / generator classes, which you can use to construct memory efficient data loaders.

For tensorflow/keras there is an excellent tutorial created by [Stanford's Shervine Amidi](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly).

For pytorch you find a good tutorial on the [project's man page](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html).

I would strongly suggest to make use of these frameworks for your implementation since they allow you to avoid writing boiler-plate code and make your training scalable.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help . But I wanted to do it manually to check How can we do it without using other generators. Below is my Code.

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpg
import numpy as np
import os

N = 0
training_labels = []

bbox = "D:/Morethan4000samples/data/labels"
imagepath = "D:/Morethan4000samples/data/image/"
for root, _, files in os.walk(imagepath):
        cdp = os.path.abspath(root)
        for f in files:
                name, ext = os.path.splitext(f)
                if ext == ".jpg":
                        cip = os.path.join(cdp,f)
                        N += 1  

print(N) 

imageX = np.zeros((N,227,227,3), dtype='float32')

i = 0

for root, _ , files in os.walk(imagepath):
        cdp = os.path.abspath(root)
        print(cdp)
        for f in files:
                ct = 0
                name, ext = os.path.splitext(f)
                if ext == ".jpg":
                        cip = os.path.join(cdp,f)
                        read = mpg.imread(cip)
                        cipLabel = cip.replace('image','labels')
                        cipLabel = cipLabel.replace('.jpg','.txt')
                        nameL , extL = os.path.splitext(cipLabel)
                        if extL == '.txt':
                                boxes = open(cipLabel, 'r')
                                for q in boxes:
                                        ct = ct + 1 
                                        if ct == 3:
                                                x1 = int(q.rsplit(' ')[0])
                                                y1 = int(q.rsplit(' ')[1])
                                                x2 = int(q.rsplit(' ')[2])
                                                y2 = int(q.rsplit(' ')[3])
                                            readimage = read[y1:y2, x1:x2]
                                            resize = cv2.cv2.resize(readimage,(227,227))
                        resize = cv2.cv2.GaussianBlur(resize, (5,5),0)
                                            imageX[i] = resize
                        #training_labels.append(int(cip.split('\\')[4]))
                        training_labels.append(int(cip.split('/')[8]))
                        print(len(training_labels), len(imageX))
                        i += 1  
                        print(i)


imageX /= 255.0
plt.imshow(imageX[10])
plt.show()

print(imageX.shape)
print(len(training_labels))

np.save("/run/media/fdai5182/LAMA MADAN/Morethan4000samples/227227/training_images", imageX)
np.save("/run/media/fdai5182/LAMA MADAN/Morethan4000samples/227227/trainin_labels",training_labels)
```

To save each of your image in a row of matrix of same dimensions is the most efficient way to do that.